# Find the number of failed Secret Santa games for N people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

N people play Secret Santa. They draw their names out of a box where:

- A person draws a name from the box
- If they draw their own name the game is failed
- Else the next person draws a name and this process repeats

I am trying to find how many failed games occurred for N people.

At first I thought this could be simply calculated by doing permutations - derangements, however this has extra permutations with numbers/people after the collision (which does not need to be accounted for since the game has failed and should start again)

I then looked at permutations with a single fixed point however the same issue arises.

Example:
For 2 people either the first person draws the others name and second draws the first players name OR the first person pick there name and the game fails. Hence for N=2, the number of failed games is 1.

Does anyone know how I could exclude these extra combinations from my approach or perhaps another way I could solve this problem?

Comment: It is just $n!$ minus the number of derangements.

Comment: I think this does not work e.g if you have 5 people: 2 possible combinations with a failed game at the 3rd person will be: {5,4,3,1,2} and another one will be {2,1,3,5,4} For this problem I should not count the second combination and any others like that for every possible failed game (hope this makes sense its hard to explain)

Comment: Okay, I get it. When $n=5$, the failed sequences look like $\{1\}, \{*,2\}, \{*,*,3\},\{*,*,*,4\},$ and $\{*,*,*,*,5\}$. You cannot just count non-derangements of the whole group, since two sequences are considered the same if they are equal up until the first failure.

Comment: I want to understand if I am counting this correctly: If $n=3$ with players labelled $1$, $2$, and $3$ based on the order of selection: Then failures are  $1$. And $2,1,3$; and $3,2$. So we would count this as $3$ failures for the $n=3$ case. Is this correct?

Comment: @paw88789 yes this is correct for n=3 there are 3 failures, for n=4 there are 8, and n=5 there are 31 (I worked these out by plugging the sequence of failures into OEIS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the players are numbered $1$ to $n$, they draw their names in numerical order, and player number $k+1$ is the first player to draw their own name. The number of ways the first $k$ people can choose numbers so that none of them draw their own name, and none of the draw name number $k+1$, can be found using the principle of inclusion-exclusion, similar to how the number of derangements are counted. The result is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}i \frac{(n-1-i)!}{(n-1-k)!}
$$
Therefore, the total number of failed sequences is found by summing that over all possible values of $k$:
$$
\boxed{\text{# failed sequences} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}i\frac{(n-1-i)!}{(n-1-k)!}}\tag1
$$
As you noted, a shifted version of this sequence appears in OEIS, with a different definition. The OEIS entry gives the simpler formula
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\tag2 {(n-1-k)!\over k!}
$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ appear to be equal for all $n$ ([confirmed](https://tio.run/##jVJBboMwELzzikVRFUxCiVPlEolTpH4jcsFOLIc1MnCoqr6drsFJSNpD92Ltjj0zO9B8dmeLb8NQSQVKXC4aT0clygTXYNg@AqoFHGzd9J1sAeM8wcyweAS0AgNFAZs9ONn1DoGP89AgpI@UkAEnWn@wKPKK5dnaVs7FwttfViDPH4bGDycSxRMMr0VZ9jWQo7FT1pGaRnACT/J26QrpO2RWfAb66uxRVBVRJRlnaappl2DWrDV73izjmSZDmWYPJJOdVRHY5guOUPC//Z9/L8PyfAsrmLu9iTw7ooj8sU0pvQW0opYgWpggFkMOJv7DkRfFuyh9ML67yukQNsTF3LWvxmnskuW70JfekVBHJAV8fS/hBfCeyoeTwty6iAjR/0F8t5moAs3BotKulhX0DYU3ctGd1yUbhh8) up to $n=150$), but I do not know how to prove this. I cannot see how $(2)$ directly relates to your failed secret Santa problem.